# Why are tags at the top of the question in the iOS app?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

We are trained to look for tags at the bottom of the question. They look like a row of divs with text in them.

[image]

Great!

Now I'm looking at a question on the mobile app, and I want to see its tags. I look down to the bottom and find my row of divs with text in them. Great! The tags. I found them. They are [favorite](/questions/tagged/favorite), [edit](/questions/tagged/edit), [share](/questions/tagged/share)... wait...

[image]

That's no tag set! That's a toolbar! Where'd my tags go? Oh right, up top... *scroll scroll scroll*...

Happens to me every time.

Feature request: put the tags at the bottom, where they belong.

Comment: They also appear at the top below the title on the Android app and on the mobile website.

Comment: Curious about the downvote. Does anyone prefer the tags up top like this? Would they go so far as to propose putting them up there on the main site? Or is it mobile specific somehow?

Comment: Yes, this is weird, especially because they are again at the bottom when editing.

Comment: This is the same in android app too. Can you add android app tag to your post?

Comment: @CRags different teams and there can be only one [tag:status-completed] tag so better have separate request for android.

Comment: abby what's this shiny red star?? Look scary. :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ok, cool! I too wondered if viewing favourite questions was possible in iOS. I assumed that was the icon to view favourite questions

Comment: @CRags don't have anything like that in my app, so it must be something unique to the new iPad app. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I am getting cross by the moment to think iOS has something android does not! Lol, even worse is iOS phone not having what iOS tablet has!

Comment: @CRags well, those with iPad were always iCooler. :P

Comment: @ShadowWizard it means you have an unfinished draft. Not black magic.

Comment: @abby thanks, never noticed! One never stop learning. :)

Comment: If I were to venture a guess, I'd say we put voting in the header to keep the question body as wide as possible (320pt was the going rate last year) and put the tags in the header because voting buttons are way taller than the title and whitespace makes us sad.

Comment: I prefer them how they are. They fit snug, it's very 'mobile'. Personally, the difference between the app/main site has never bothered me (never even realised it till this question!), but if one was to change - id prefer it be the main site. If we're carrying on with this 'no tags in titles' malarky, then the tags are important to know what you're about to read about - so I need to see them when I first open a page, I don't want to read the title, scroll down to the bottom, and then read the main text.

Comment: This is obviously less of an issue on the main site, as questions are normally short enough to show both top and bottom in the same widow, but not so often on my iPhone :-(

Comment: @Chris, to be honest, I wouldn't mind that. I could get used to them being at the top on the main site. I just want them to be in the same place in every device I use to look at an SE question.

Comment: That's a fair point. I wouldn't want them to be bottom in the app though - I'd prefer usability over consistency! =)

Comment: @Chris, I argue that inconsistency inhibits usability. I always go look for the tags in the place I'm used to seeing them, and then have to scroll around and look for them when they're someone else. Bad UX!

Comment: I completely agree! But this is a lesser-of-two-evils situation, and I'd say making me scroll down to see what is effectively part of the title is the worse case of the two.